# String format negative number minus sign (no parantheses) in java or groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have used **String.format('$%(,.2f', -125.433)** to output the string as $(125.43).

What should be X in **String.format('X', -125.43)** to output as -$125.43 ie. prepend a minus sign?

Or, how can I do that alternatively?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid format string for `String.format` in Java.  Were you using `DecimalFormat`?  (I don't know anything about Groovy.)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use java.text.DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("$#,###0.000;$-#,###0.000");
String formatted = format.format(-125.433);
System.out.println(formatted); // prints $-125.433
```

Or you can stick to using string format as mentioned in the comment bellow by @biplavo.

```
String.format("$%,.3f", -125.433)
```

Comment: I think he wanted the `-` before the `$`, and probably only two decimal places, but this looks like the right idea.

Comment: He can update the format string to `"$#,###0.000;-$#,###0.000"` that should do the trick.

Comment: String.format('$%,.2f', -125.433) does the same thing as you  mentioned. I have tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Groovy, so I will not attempt to provide that solution. However, I can say with some confidence that this is a case where `String.format` isn't particularly useful. I'd just use `?:` like this:

```
public static String formatMoney(double d){
    return d>=0?"$"+d:"-$"+(-d);
}
```

And of course this can be inlined; you can also replace `d` in both cases with your basic formatting case.

Comment: He should string use `String.format("%.2f")` or something to format the string as two decimal places.  Then he can apply your suggestion and include the result of `String.format` in the expression.

Comment: Yes, I'm using similar like this. But not convinced enough. So, thought that there may be something simpler as I've mentioned above. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Maybe a `SimpleDecimalFormat` but that seems more trouble than it's worth

Answer (score 0):

Groovy!!

```
String format(BigDecimal num = 0.0) {
    num = ( num ?: 0.0 ).setScale( 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP )
    num >= 0 ? /$($num)/ : /-$${num.abs()}/
}

assert format(123.433  ) == /$(123.43)/
assert format(-123.433 ) == /-$123.43/
assert format(1        ) == /$(1.00)/
assert format(0        ) == /$(0.00)/
assert format(111      ) == /$(111.00)/
assert format(-101     ) == /-$101.00/
assert format(-1123.435) == /-$1123.44/
assert format(1123.435 ) == /$(1123.44)/
assert format(null     ) == /$(0.00)/
assert format(         ) == /$(0.00)/
```